# OpenCV: solvePnP tvec units and axes directions

Tags: python, opencv, coordinate-systems, camera-calibration

I'm trying to find the relative position of the camera to the chessboard (or the other way around) - I feel OK with converting between different coordinate systems, e.g. as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444433/calculate-camera-world-position-with-opencv-python?rq=1). I decided to use chessboard not only for calibration but actual position determination as well at this stage, since I can use the `findChessboardCorners` to get the `imagePoints` (and this works OK).

I've read a lot on this topic and feel that I understand the `solvePnP` outputs (even though I'm completely new to `openCV` and computer vision in general). Unfortunately, the results I get from `solvePnP` and physically measuring the test set-up are different: translation in z-direction is off by approx. 25%. `x` and `y` directions are completely wrong - several orders of magnitude and different direction than what I've read to be the camera coordinate system (x pointing up the image, y to the right, z away from the camera). The difference persists if I convert `tvec` and `rvec` to camera pose in world coordinates.

My questions are:

- What are the directions of camera and world coordinate systems' axes?
- Does `solvePnP` output the translation in the same units as I specify the `objectPoints`?
- I specified the world origin as the first of the `objectPoints` (one of the chessboard corners). Is that OK and is `tvec` the translation to exactly that point from the camera coordinates?

This is my code (I attach it *pro forma* as it does not throw any exceptions etc.). I used grayscale images to get the camera intrinsics matrix and distortion coefficients during calibration so decided to perform localisation in grayscale as well. `chessCoordinates` is a list of chessboard points location in mm with respect to the origin (one of the corner points). `camMatrix` and `distCoefficients` come from calibration (performed using the same chessboard and `objectPoints`).

```
camCapture=cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Take a picture of the target to get the imagePoints 
tempImg=camCapture.read()
imgPts=[]
tgtPts=[]

tempImg=cv2.cvtColor(tempImg[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
found_all, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(tempImg, chessboardDim )

imgPts.append(corners.reshape(-1, 2))
tgtPts.append(np.array(chessCoordinates, dtype=np.float32))

retval,myRvec,myTvec=cv2.solvePnP(objectPoints=np.array(tgtPts), imagePoints=np.array(imgPts), cameraMatrix=camMatrix, distCoeffs=distCoefficients)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The camera coordinates are the same as image coordinates. So You have x axe pointing in the right side from the camera, y axe pointing down, and z pointing in the direction camera is faced. This is a clockwise axe system, and the same would apply to the chessboard, so if You specified the origin in, lets say, upper right corner of the chessboard, x axe goes along the longer side to the right and y along shorter side of the chessboard, z axe would be pointing downward, to the ground.

Solve PnP outputs the translation in the same units as the units in which You specified the length of chessboard fields, but it might also use units specified in camera calibration, as it uses the camera matrix.

Tvec points to the origin of the world coordinates in which You placed the calibration object. So if You placed the first object point in (0,0), thats where tvec will point to.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot. I've come accross some of this stuff somewhere before, but it's good to get some reassurance. Also, explanation of the coordiate system axes is hugely useful, as I haven't come accross something like this. Cheers.

Comment: @morynicz accidentally downvoted this great answer, now my vote is locked :( apparently you need to edit it in order for me to undo...

Answer (score 4):

**What are the directions of camera and world coordinate systems' axes?**

The 0,0,0 corner on the boards is so that the X & Y axis are towards the rest of the corner points. The Z axis is always pointing away from the board. This means that it's usually pointing somewhat in the direction of the camera.

**Does solvePnP output the translation in the same units as I specify the objectPoints?**

Yes

**I specified the world origin as the first of the objectPoints (one of the chessboard corners). Is that OK and is tvec the translation to exactly that point from the camera coordinates?**

Yes, this is pretty common. In most of the cases, the first cam corner is set as 0,0,0 and subsequent corners being set at the z=0 plane (eg; (1,0,0) , (0,1,0), etc).

The tvec, combined with the rotation, points towards that point from the board coordinate frame toward the camera. In short; the tvec & rvec provide you with the inverse translation (world -> camera). With some basic geometry you can calculate the transformation that puts camera -> world.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick response. What about the camera coordinate system axes - where do they "point"?

"The tvec, combined with the rotation, points towards that point from the board coordinate frame **toward** the camera." According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515200/python-opencv-solvepnp-yields-wrong-translation-vector) tvec is in camera coordinates (not "toward the camera"). Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think (but i'm not entirely sure) that the camera coordinate system Z points away from the camera (in the direction it is "looking"). 
What i mean is that there is a difference between the world coordinate frame and the camera coordinate frame. You can convert a point that is in the "board frame" to the "camera frame" by using the rvec & tvec. If you want to convert a point from the camera frame to the world frame, you need to use the inverse of both.

Comment: Thanks, I've already worked it out with big help from the above answer and your one too. It all makes a lot of sense now. Cheers.